# JTable and ListSelectionListener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have a `JTable` with contact names in. On selecting a row from this table a second table is filled with that person's primary phone number and email address. At the moment I am using a custom `MouseListener` to check when people are clicking on a row in the first table, but I also want them to be able to scroll through the list with their keyboard.

I have used `ListSelectionListener` on `JList`s in the past and vaguely remember someone saying that `ListSelectionListener` could be used on a JTable, but have been unable to find anywhere explaining how.

So, my question is.. Can `ListSelectionListener` (or similar) be used on a `JTable`? If so, how?

Image below - The image's Table is blurred so it probably doesn't help much;

[image]

Comment: the same way as on a list, unless you have individual cell selection enabled

Comment: @Jonas Eicher - There is no `addListSelectionListener()` method for `JTable`. So they can't be added the same way as on a JList.

Comment: I meant what camickr wrote in his answer. JTable just doesnt have the convenience-method that JList provides (is delegates to the ListSelectionModel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JTable works like a JList because it also has a ListSelectionModel. So you would just use:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListSelectionListener` works on `SelectionModel` and since our table also has a `selectionModel` therefore we cann apply it on `JTable` as well.

```
tablename.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(argument);
```